# Adjustable span tag for showing onclick event count

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

I currently have a span tag which displays the onclick count for a button. Right now if the number exceeds three digits it will not fit within the span tag. Can I make the span tag adjustable or can I make its width adjustable, so that it will always encompass the onclick count?

I can change the width to accommodate more digits but I would like it to be adjustable because I cannot predict how many onclick events will actually occur.

```
var counts = {
  'Apples': 0,
  'Oranges': 0,
  'total': 0
};

   function countFruit(type) {
   document.getElementById('fruitCount').innerHTML = ++counts['total'];
   document.getElementById(type + 'Count').innerHTML = ++counts[type];
}


#OrangesCount{
z-index: 20;
position:absolute;
top:70px;
left:45%;
background-color:black;
width:80px;
border:2px solid green;
font-family: 'BPdotsUnicaseSquareBold';
font-size:25px;
color:yellow;
padding-right:4px;
padding-left:4px;
 }


#ApplesCount{
z-index: 20;
position:absolute;
color:yellow;
top:70px;
right:45%;
background-color:black;
width:80px;
border:2px solid green;
font-family: 'BPdotsUnicaseSquareBold';
font-size:25px;
   }

   <a id="buttonright" href="#" onclick="countFruit('Apples'); return false;">
   <a id="buttonleft" href="#" onclick="countFruit('Oranges'); return false;">

   <span id="ApplesCount"></span>
   <span id="OrangesCount"></span>
```

Comment: It should auto-adjust, can we see the code, at least a snippet, or a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.com)?

Comment: Here is some code. Let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove `width` from both css:

```
#ApplesCount{
    z-index: 20;
    position:absolute;
    color:yellow;
    top:70px;
    right:45%;
    background-color:black;
    border:2px solid #550010;
    font-family: 'BPdotsUnicaseSquareBold';
    font-size:25px;
}
```

Here's [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fPdA7/)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to allow an element to automatically adjust its width, do not make its width fixed. You can specify a minimum width instead, like below example CSS.

```
#OrangesCount{
z-index: 20;
position:absolute;
top:70px;
left:45%;
background-color:black;

/*removed
width:80px;
*/
min-width:80px;

border:2px solid #001855;
font-family: 'BPdotsUnicaseSquareBold';
font-size:25px;
color:yellow;
padding-right:4px;
padding-left:4px;
}


#ApplesCount{
z-index: 20;
position:absolute;
color:yellow;
top:70px;
right:45%;
background-color:black;

/*removed
width:80px;
*/
min-width:80px;

border:2px solid #550010;
font-family: 'BPdotsUnicaseSquareBold';
font-size:25px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that Jay. I will be using this in the future.